# Using rails + devise but getting Failed to Login and Signed in successfully in different browsers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

Having setup a simple devise rails app with:
`:database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable` I am seeing different results in two browsers or within the same browser and incognito mode.

I register fine and it logs me in instantly, if i logout and try logging again i will find the message `Failed to Login`, where does it come from? Can I debug or inspect more of it?

Going to incognito mode in Chrome, or using a different browser logs me in almost instantly, without seeing that Failed to Login message.

I can almost never replicate this in development mode, but on Heroku it's happening constantly.

Any clues to even start debugging?

Comment: Why don't you start by sharing some code, will help to see whats happening

Comment: Definitely give us some code to look at. From what you describe, I'd be suspecting session-variables, and that heroku has more than one dyno (and doesn't share sessions)? Are you using database-sessions?

Comment: Not using database sessions, one dyno only as well. There isnt much code except boilerplate devise, I would love to post more stacktrace from the server but even that is just inconclusive unauthorized 401

Comment: Why did it fail? You should show the error message to see what happen. It's the way of tracking error, we need to see details

Comment: Is there any reference in devise to 'failed to login' string?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error, and here's my findings and solution incase it helps others in the future.

The `Failed to Login` message actually comes from Warden, which is packed under Devise. https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/blob/5b3cbd5bef67cbe399bb7007537bc4841bbee772/lib/warden/strategies/base.rb#L136

So, as devise is going through it's list of strategies to test for authentication, if any of them call `strategy.fail!` the process will halt, and the failure message will be passed up the chain to device to display in the flash message. In this case, that's the message you see.

For me, this was happening because my JWT token was failing to decode, and my custom devise strategy for handling the JWT tokens was rescuing and calling `fail!` without a custom error message in that case. This approach looks a little safer as it will pass a more helpful message: https://medium.com/@lukerollans/implementing-jwt-authentication-as-a-custom-devise-strategy-54948bddb134

So I guess one of your devise strategies is calling `fail` or `fail!` somewhere along the way. Good luck!